# "Foreign" messages in syslog and dmesg -- system breached or side effect of VPS?

Tags: 14.04, server, syslog, dmesg

I am running a small Ubuntu 14.04 server on a VPS offering. Since a few days ago, the system seems to crash (almost) daily.

My application logs did not help a lot, but I noticed these log entries in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Oct 17 10:46:24 {{SYSTEM_NAME}} kernel: [169670.665018] audit: type=1302 audit(1571301984.508:1710939): item=0 name="/home/gameserver/servers/{{REDACTED_IP}}_27015/ark/steamclient.so" inode=1443776 dev=07:07 mode=0120777 ouid=100500 ogid=100500 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
Oct 17 10:46:24 {{SYSTEM_NAME}} kernel: [169670.808472] audit: type=1302 audit(1571301984.648:1710943): item=0 name="/home/gameserver/servers/{{REDACTED_IP}}_27015/ark/ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/BattlEye/BEClient_x64.so" inode=1445759 dev=07:07 mode=0120777 ouid=100500 ogid=100500 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
Oct 17 10:46:24 {{SYSTEM_NAME}} kernel: [169670.808568] audit: type=1302 audit(1571301984.648:1710947): item=0 name="/home/gameserver/servers/{{REDACTED_IP}}_27015/ark/ShooterGame/Binaries/Linux/BattlEye/EULA.txt" inode=1445758 dev=07:07 mode=0120777 ouid=100500 ogid=100500 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0000000000000000 cap_fi=0000000000000000 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0
```

where {{SYSTEM_NAME}} **is** my server's name and {{REDACTED_IP}} is **not** my server's IP. I also do not have a `gameserver`user or home folder, nor do I have anything Steam related running on the system. Messages about these files are also in `/var/log/dmesg`.

I am not quite sure what to make of this. Do I have to consider my system breached, or is this a side effect of running on a VPS (maybe with bad configuration)?

Comment: Are you using steam on that machine? If not, then yes: it does sound like someone else has been on your system. You could still try and figure out what was changed (hint: /var/log/apt/history.log, /root/.bash_history, /home/*/.bash_history, some `ls -ltr /etc` to highlight last modified files, ...). Though the quickest way to get them out may just be to re-install, or migrate to a new server.

Comment: @SYN All the bash_histories look fine and I could not find unwanted changes or logins. Since the folder in question (´/home/gameserver´) does not even exist on the system, I looked into the IP that was in the folder structure. It seems to belong to my VPS provider's IP range indeed.